# Does Windows 10 "hibernate after sleep" wake the machine before hibernating?

Tags: windows-10, sleep, hibernate

In Windows 10, it is set as

```
 Turn off the display/screensaver: Never 
 Sleep after: 10 minutes 
 Hibernate after: 30 minutes
```

At 0:10, the PC sleeps, and the screen goes blank

What happens at 0:30?

does it

1. fully wake up (login screen shows up) and then hibernates
2. hibernates directly from sleep (computer appears to be shut down, screen remains blank)
3. remains in sleep mode and disregards hibernate

Answer (score 1):

It cannot “hibernate from sleep”. It has to wake up and write the memory contents to disk. Of course, it doesn’t have to activate the screen to do so.

When it’s time to hibernate, you can find the following event in the System log:

> The system has returned from a low power state.
>
> Sleep Time: ‎2017‎-‎01‎-‎20T18:38:20.615607200Z
>   Wake Time: ‎2017‎-‎01‎-‎20T18:38:20.608105500Z
>
> Wake Source: S4 Doze to Hibernate

A few seconds later, it will start the hibernation process:

> The system is entering sleep.
>
> Sleep Reason: Hibernate from Sleep - Fixed Timeout

I’d guess the screen isn’t activated for this, but I haven’t actually observed it.